# Android jni broadcast to java

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, native, broadcast

I'm currently working on (an existing) Android app using native c++ code. I want send a broadcast to another Android Java app listening to a BroadcastReceiver. The receiving app is yet working, but I can't figure out how to broadcast data from JNI code either directly or by sending the values to java code and them broadcasting it from Java.

[image: Example]

I hope my explanaion is clear. Can someone help me on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to do it in Java and write a JNI callback to call that Java function.  If you do need to do it in C, you'll need to use JNI to create an Intent, then to set the action and extras of the intent, then use JNI to call the sendBroadcast method of your activity to actually send it.  Its a lot of boilerplate JNI code, so I'd try to avoid it.

Comment: Then how would I do the callback? I have absolutely no experience in C, but much more in Java. I have the Java code ready, the only problem is calling the java function and especially the transfer of the C variables to java. Can you maybe supply me with an example?

Comment: If you need help with that, you should read some JNI tutorials.  The basics is you write a function in Java to do it, look up its method ID, and invoke it.  It's a pretty trivial piece of JNI.

Comment: I've been searching for so many examples, but I can't get it to work properly. I constantly get stuck on JNIEnv* etc. It's probably just that env that I can't get to set up properly. As I said, I've just started C++ so I'm sorry for probably some stupid questions.

Comment: By now I have solved my problem by calling the JNI function from Java and then returning the wanted data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to implement all logic in a Java method:

```
public class MyClass {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("mylib_jni");
  }

  public static final String ACTION_TEST = "com.example.action.TEST";
  private final LocalBroadCastManager broadcastManager;

  public MyClass(Context context) {
    broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private void onSendText(String text) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_TEST).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
  }

  private native void sendText();   
}
```

and just call that method from JNI:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_MyClass_1sendText(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
  jclass clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, instance);
  jmethodID method = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "onSendText", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
  jstring text = (*env)->NewString(env, "test message");
  (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, instance, method, text);
}
```